# PHP number calculation, strange result

Tags: php, numbers

For the following

```
echo 0.02-0.01-0.06+0.05;
```

I got result is

```
6.93889390391E-18
```

For this one

```
echo -0.02+0.02;
```

I got result

```
0
```

I want to know why i got the different result for those to. I suppose to get two `0` result.

Comment: `echo (0.06+0.05)-(0.02-0.01);` = 0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) work.

Comment: How to prevent this? Because I want to get 0 but not other value.

Comment: "prevent" - you can't, really. But you can simply [round](http://php.net/round) it to a "good" number. `round(0.02-0.01-0.06+0.05,10)` will give you `0`. Note that even `round` can mess up floats, but it's fairly rare.

Answer (score 1):

floating point arithmetic doesn't really correlate strongly to normal mathematical rules. For example, operations aren't associative or distributive.

floating point representations are approximations with limited precision.

this isnt a php specific thing - computers simply cant represent numbers like we conceptualize them.

Comment: This particular case may be a PHP thing in that PHP's floating point representation scheme handles the numbers involved poorly to some extent, but other schemata may do better.  For instance, Perl, Python, Ruby and, somewhat hilariously, Wolfram Alpha (in its prepop) give the same result as PHP, but Pike gives 0.

Answer (score 1):

When you write numerals “0.02” in source code, the compiler or interpreter uses floating-point to represent them. The most common floating-point format is IEEE 754 binary floating-point, either single-precision or double-precision.

This floating-point format cannot represent most decimal numerals exactly. For example, just as decimals cannot represent 1/3 exactly (it is approximately .3333, but any decimal numeral of finite length ends somewhere, so it differs slightly from 1/3), the binary numerals used in floating-point cannot represent 1/10 exactly (in binary, 1/10 is approximately .000110011001100110011).

Therefore, when you write “0.02-0.01-0.06+0.05”, the computer is not doing arithmetic with exactly those numbers. It is using close approximations. So the result you get is a close approximation.

If you want an exact result, you must either learn the details of floating-point arithmetic so that you can craft operations that avoid error or for which the error can be corrected or you should use only integer arithmetic. For example, if the above represented dollars amounts to be added and subtracted, you could instead store penny amounts and calculate “2-1-6+5”.

Answer (score 0):

If you round it to two or three decimal places, this will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just for someone hiting this problem, you can use the arbitrary precision functions from BCMath library
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

```
echo 12606.69 + 3053.46 - 15660.15;
1.8189894035459E-12
```

and

```
echo bcadd((12606.69 + 3053.46),-15660.15);
0
```